# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2014 Database using Spring Boot

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database using Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver 8.2 (mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar) with Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;autoReconnect=true;useSSL=false
```

when starting the application, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getLong(SQLServerResultSet.java:2340)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

Comment: One of your fields is the wrong type

Comment: Is your Shift key broken again Mahmoud?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your sequence data type from INTEGER to BIGINT. Apparently, this used to work in older version of hibernate.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/issues